# Count nodes bigger then root in each subtree of a given binary tree in O(n log n)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

We are given a tree with `n` nodes in form of a pointer to its root node, where each node contains a pointer to its parent, left child and right child, and also a key which is an integer. For each node `v` I want to add additional field `v.bigger` which should contain number of nodes with key bigger than `v.key`, that are in a subtree rooted at `v`. Adding such a field to all nodes of a tree should take `O(n log n)` time in total.

I'm looking for any hints that would allow me to solve this problem. I tried several heuristics - for example when thinking about doing this problem in bottom-up manner, for a fixed node `v`, `v.left` and `v.right` could provide `v` with some kind of set (balanced BST?) with operation `bigger(x)`, which for a given `x` returns a number of elements bigger than `x` in that set in logarihmic time. The problem is, we would need to merge such sets in `O(log n)`, so this seems as a no-go, as I don't know any ordered set like data structure which supports quick merging.

I also thought about top-down approach - a node `v` adds one to some `u.bigger` for some node `u` if and only if `u` lies on a simple path to the root and `u<v`. So `v` could update all such `u`'s somehow, but I couldn't come up with any reasonable way of doing that...

So, what is the right way of thinking about this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perform depth-first search in given tree (starting from root node).

When any node is visited for the first time (coming from parent node), add its key to some order-statistics data structure (OSDS). At the same time query OSDS for number of keys larger than current key and initialize `v.bigger` with negated result of this query.

When any node is visited for the last time (coming from right child), query OSDS for number of keys larger than current key and add the result to `v.bigger`.

You could apply this algorithm to any rooted trees (not necessarily binary trees). And it does not necessarily need parent pointers (you could use DFS stack instead).

For OSDS you could use either augmented BST or Fenwick tree. In case of Fenwick tree you need to preprocess given tree so that values of the keys are compressed: just copy all the keys to an array, sort it, remove duplicates, then substitute keys by their indexes in this array.

Comment: So simple... I can't believe I haven't come up with that ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Basic idea:**

Using the bottom-up approach, each node will get two ordered lists of the values in the subtree from both sons and then find how many of them are bigger. When finished, pass the combined ordered list upwards.

**Details:**

1. Leaves:
   Leaves obviously have `v.bigger=0`. The node above them creates a two item list of the values, updates itself and adds its own value to the list.
2. All other nodes:
   Get both lists from sons and merge them in an ordered way. Since they are already sorted, this is `O(number of nodes in subtree)`. During the merge you can also find how many nodes qualify the condition and get the value of `v.bigger` for the node.

**Why is this O(n logn)?**

Every node in the tree counts through the number of nodes in its subtree. This means the root counts all the nodes in the tree, the sons of the root each count (combined) the number of nodes in the tree (yes, yes, `-1` for the root) and so on all nodes in the same height count together the number of nodes that are lower. This gives us that the number of nodes counted is `number of nodes` * `height of the tree` -  which is `O(n logn)`

Comment: Your answer is not `O(n log n)` under worst case scenario (every node has only one child except the leaf). I won't down vote because the author never clarified whether he's looking for worst case complexity or expected case complexity. Additionally, in order to get expected case `O(n log n)` complexity, there are easier solutions.

Comment: @Haozhun - I kinda disagree. In your worst case scenario, where we have all the children on one long branch (in my native language we refer to this as a "shoelace" or "rope" or "string"), each node will receive an empty list from one son and a (long) list from the other son. combining these lists is `O(1)`. You also mentioned there are other ways? please elaborate.

Comment: Let's consider trees like this then: T(i) = tree(T(i-1), T(0)), T(0) = tree(nil, nil). In this case, T(m) is a tree of m*2+1 nodes, and has depth of m.

Comment: @Haozhun - you're right - that example would cost `O(n^2)`. So what is the solution you were talking about?

Answer (score -1):

What if for each node we keep a separate binary search tree (BST) which consists of nodes of the subtree rooted at that node.

For a node `v` at level `k`, merging the two subtrees `v.left` and `v.right` which both have `O(n/2^(k+1))` elements is `O(n/2^k)`. After forming the BST for this node, we can find v.bigger in `O(n/2^(k+1))` time by just counting the elements in the right (traditionally) subtree of the BST. Summing up, we have `O(3*n/2^(k+1))` operations for a single node at level `k`. There are a total of `2^k` many level k nodes, therefore we have `O(2^k*3*n/2^(k+1))` which is simplified as O(n) (dropping the 3/2 constant). operations at level `k`. There are `log(n)` levels, hence we have `O(n*log(n))` operations in total.

Comment: Calculate now how many nodes you have to store in worst case. It will be O(N^2)

Comment: @SashaMN I don't get your point, are you referring to the space complexity? You don't have to maintain all the BSTs at once, once a level is formed you can just discard the BSTs of the level below (level that is higher in value).

Comment: While I don't agree with the downvote, I can explain what @SashaMN meant in the comment. Your solution assumes that the tree is reasonably balanced, i.e. the depth of the tree is `O(log N)`, which is not necessarily true. (OP didn't say.) Without this assumption, your solution is `O(N^2)`.